# finding edge in tilted image with Canny

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection, canny-operator

I'm trying to find the tilt angle in a series of images which look like the created example data below. There should be a clear edge which is visible by eye. However I'm struggling in extracting the edges so far. Is Canny the right way of finding the edge here or is there a better way of finding the edge?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

# create data
xvals = np.arange(0,2000)
yvals = 10000 * np.exp((xvals - 1600)/200) + 100
yvals[1600:] = 100
blurred = gaussian_filter(yvals, sigma=20)

# create image
img = np.tile(blurred,(2000,1))
img = np.swapaxes(img,0,1)

# rotate image
rows,cols = img.shape
M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),3.7,1)
img = cv.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

# convert to uint8 for Canny
img_8 = cv.convertScaleAbs(img,alpha=(255.0/65535.0))
fig,ax = plt.subplots(3)
ax[0].plot(xvals,blurred)
ax[1].imshow(img)

# find edge
ax[2].imshow(cv.Canny(img_8, 20, 100, apertureSize=5))
```

[image: sample image for edge detection]

Comment: Are the colours always the much the same in all images? Or could they be, say, orange and magenta? Is the line whose angle you are try find always straight, or could it be wavy?

Comment: hey, so actually it's a greyscale image (that's just the matplotlib representation of it). The angle is always straight with some additional noise.

Comment: What would be the expected maximum/minimum angle to the horizon? +/- 45 degrees? +/- 90 degrees?

Comment: Is speed a concern, or irrelevant?

Comment: the expected angle is +- 15 degress and speed is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thresholding as suggested by kavko didn't work that well, as the intensity varied from image to image (I could of course consider the histogram for each image to imrove this approach). I ended up with taking the maximum of the gradient in the y-direction:

```
def rotate_image(image):
    blur = ndimage.gaussian_filter(image, sigma=10)    # blur image first
    grad = np.gradient(blur, axis= 0)    # take gradient along y-axis
    grad[grad>10000]=0    # filter unreasonable high values
    idx_maxline = np.argmax(grad, axis=0)    # get y-indices of max slope = indices of edge

    mean = np.mean(idx_maxline)
    std = np.std(idx_maxline)
    idx = np.arange(idx_maxline.shape[0])
    idx_filtered = idx[(idx_maxline < mean+std) & (idx_maxline > mean - std)]    # filter positions where highest slope is at different position(blobs)
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(idx_filtered, idx_maxline[idx_filtered])
    out = ndimage.rotate(image,slope*180/np.pi, reshape = False)
    return out
out = rotate_image(img)
plt.imshow(out)
```

[image: final rotated image]

Answer (score 3):

You can find the angle by transforming your image to binary (`cv2.threshold(cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`) then search for contours.

[image]

When you locate your contour (line) then you can fit a line on your contour `cv2.fitLine()` and get two points of your line. My math is not very good but I think that in linear equation the formula goes `f(x) = k*x + n` and you can get `k` out of those two points (`k = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`) and finally the angle `phi = arctan(k)`. (If I'm wrong please correct it)

You can also use the rotated bounding rectangle - `cv2.minAreaRect()` - which already returns the angle of the rectangle (`rect = cv2.minAreaRect()` --> `rect[2]`). Hope it helps. Cheers!

Here is an example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

img = cv2.imread('angle.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, False)
    if area < 10001 and 100 < perimeter < 1000:
        # first approach - fitting line and calculate with y=kx+n --> angle=tan^(-1)k
        rows,cols = img.shape[:2]
        [vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(c, cv2.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
        lefty = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)
        righty = int(((cols-x)*vy/vx)+y)
        cv2.line(img,(cols-1,righty),(0,lefty),(0,255,0),2)
        (x1, y1) = (cols-1, righty)
        (x2, y2) = (0, lefty)
        k = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
        angle = math.atan(k)*180/math.pi
        print(angle)
        #second approch - cv2.minAreaRect --> returns center (x,y), (width, height), angle of rotation )
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
        print(rect[2])

cv2.imshow('img2', img)
```

Original image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

-3.8493663478518627

-3.7022125720977783

Answer (score 2):

tribol,

it seems like you can take the gradient image G = |Gx| + |Gy| (normalize it to some known range), calc its Histogram and take the top bins of it. it will give you approx mask of the line. Then you can do line fitting. It'll give you a good initial guess.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of doing it is as follows... adjust my numbers to suit your knowledge of the data.

Normalise your image to a scale of 0-255.

Choose two points A and B, where A is 10% of the image width in from the left side and B is 10% in from the right side. The distance AB is now 0.8 x 2000, or 1600 px.

Go North from point A sampling your image till you exceed some sensible threshold that means you have met the tilted line. Note the Y value at this point, as YA.

Do the same, going North from point B till you meet the tilted line. Note the Y value at this point, as YB.

The angle you seek is:

```
tan-1((YB-YA)/1600)
```

[image]