# Measuring true angle of a bended wire with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have a robotic device that bends wire, and I try to measure whether the bending was successful by looking at the desired and true angle measurements.

[image: Original and color adjusted images]

What I have in mind is to detect the wire and draw a line for each segment of the wire, after that it becomes just a little trigonometry problem. But I can not find a way to draw and get coordinates of those lines.

I'm very new to image processing so please excuse my crude terminology.

Comment: Take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169162/finding-edge-in-tilted-image-with-canny/51177368#51177368
It will maybe give you an idea

Comment: You might consider Canny edge detection and then Hough line detection. From the hough line endpoints, you can find the slope/intersections of each and then find the intersection of the two relevant lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an interesting problem. We can use the fact that the vertical edge strength of the bent wire and unbent wire is different. The unbent wire will return a higher value when we filter it with vertical Sobel filter.

Result of sobel filter in the y-direction

[image]

Extract the bent and unbent wire by extracting the region(blobs) of different strength.

> Stronger edge will correspond to the unbent wire.
>
> Weaker edge will correspond to the bent wire.

[image][image]

By using opencv blob analysis function *minRectArea*, we can obtain the angle, size and center position of the blobs.

[image]

The angle value w.r.t. horizontal line

> Unbent Wire : 3.94 degree
>
> Bent Wire : 21.37 degree

Here is the code used to obtain the above result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# extract blob with largest area
def get_best_blob(blobs):
    best_blob = None
    best_size = 0
    for i,blob in enumerate(blobs):
        rot_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(blob)
        (cx,cy),(sx,sy),angle = rot_rect
        if sx * sy >best_size :
            best_blob = rot_rect
            best_size = sx * sy
    
    return best_blob

def draw_blob_rect(frame,blob,color):
    box = cv2.boxPoints(blob)
    box = np.int0(box)    
    frame = cv2.drawContours(frame,[box],0,color,1)

    return frame

def process():
    image = cv2.imread("wire.png")

    # Change to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Reduce size for speed
    gray = cv2.resize(gray,(0,0),fx=0.5,fy=0.5)

    # Extract wire region
    _ , thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # morphology kernel
    kernel = np.array((
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1]
            ), dtype="int")
    
    # Get y-edges
    dy = cv2.Sobel(thresh,cv2.CV_32F,0,1,ksize=21)

    # remove negative values
    dy = dy * dy
    
    # Normalize it to 255
    cv2.normalize(dy,dy,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX,alpha=255)
    dy = dy.astype('uint8')

    # Extract relevant information
    # Stronger edge is the original part
    # Weaker edge is the bended part
    _ , strong = cv2.threshold(dy,0.95 * 255,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    _ , mid = cv2.threshold(dy,0.5 * 255,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


    # Morphological closing to remove holes 
    strong_temp = cv2.dilate(strong,kernel, iterations=5)
    strong = cv2.erode(strong_temp,kernel, iterations=5)
    
    # remove the strong part from the mid
    mid = cv2.subtract(mid,strong_temp)

    # Morphological closing to remove holes 
    mid_temp = cv2.dilate(mid,kernel, iterations=5)
    mid = cv2.erode(mid_temp,kernel, iterations=5)

    # find the blobs for each bin image
    _,strong_blobs,_ = cv2.findContours(strong,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    _,mid_blobs,_ = cv2.findContours(mid,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # get the blob with the largest area
    best_strong = get_best_blob(strong_blobs)
    best_mid = get_best_blob(mid_blobs)

    # print the angle
    print( "strong_angle",90 + best_strong[2])
    print( "mid_angle",90 + best_mid[2])

    
    # Draw the segmented Box region
    display_frame = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    display_frame = draw_blob_rect(display_frame,best_strong,(0,0,255))
    display_frame = draw_blob_rect(display_frame,best_mid,(0,255,255))
    
    # draw result    
    cv2.imshow("display_frame",display_frame)
    cv2.imshow("mid",mid)
    cv2.imshow("strong",strong)
    cv2.imshow("image",image)
    cv2.imshow("dy",dy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)



if __name__=='__main__':
    process()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very helpful. After diving in your code  realized that you change threshold slightly to get different regions of the wire. I tried to edit the code to get the regions when wire is bent three times and managed to get all three of them, but it seems that it gets pretty complicated when the number of bendings increase. Is there any other way to get those regions when the number of regions is arbitrary?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question so my answer will also be somewhat broad. One way to go about it would be this:

1. Threshold to get binary image where the wire becomes white, background black
2. Perform connected components labeling
3. Draw only second largest component on a black new image (ignoring the disc shape on the left)
4. Sum this image vertically to find the transition from the base of the wire to the wire (jump in column sum value)
5. Determine the y coordinate of the topmost white pixel for every column from the tip of the wire (leftmost non-zero sum column) to just before the base of the wire
6. Compute the distance of each of these topmost pixels to the line between the leftmost top pixel and the rightmost top pixel (just before the base)
7. Locate the inflection point as the top pixel in the column for which this distance is maximal
8. Compute the angle of the line between the leftmost top pixel and the inflection point
9. Compare to the horizontal, or to the angle of the line between inflection point and rightmost top pixel before the base if this part can also be skewed